# Is it possible to forward all traffic from one Ethernet interface to another without NAT?

Tags: routing

Set up:
Cable modem --> HW Ethernet port on Ubuntu 16 box (eth0).
OpenVPN client connection (tun0) over eth0.
2nd HW Ethernet port on Ubuntu 16 box (eth1) to hardware router.

I can set up internet sharing over eth1 and run that as a DHCP server with typical 10.42.0.0.

Assume for iptables that eth0 has 192.168.1.1, tun0 has 60.60.1.1, and eth1 has 10.42.0.1.

Is it possible to simply have all the data coming in and out of eth0 be sent to eth1, without this masquerade? That way, all data from the cable modem WAN is flowing through the Ubuntu box to the hardware router, but the hardware router can still do its NAT job without the Ubuntu box doing it in between. Is this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: You can bridge `eth0` and `eth1`, which would mean they are effectively on the same LAN segment and need the same address range. Also, everything behind `eth1` and the hardware router would be directly connected to the cable modem, and get addresses via DHCP from it, so I guess that would be 192.168.1.0/24. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

If `eth0` has `192.168.1.1` then you've already got NAT somewhere in the equation, either as CGNAT (in which case maybe consider changing ISP) or inside the cable modem. If `tun0` has `60.*` then it's using a public IP address.

You can definitely forward traffic between interfaces without NAT. It's called forwarding.

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

You also need to set up the routing so that your cable modem knows not only about its directly connected subnet `192.168.1.1/24` but also the other subnets in your network, principally `10.42.0.0/??`.